# Adding !important marker to Clay CSS rules

Tags: haskell, clay-css

I'm using [Clay](http://fvisser.nl/clay/) to generate CSS rules in Haskell.
For example:

```haskell
cssStyle :: Css
cssStyle = body ? paddingTop (px 60)
```

generates this CSS:

```css
body {padding-top : 60px;}
```

How can I add an `!important` tag to this rule that yields

```
body {padding-top : 60px !important;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`-:`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/clay-0.10.1/docs/Clay-Stylesheet.html#v:-45-:) operator to specify a custom value:

```
cssStyle :: Css
cssStyle = body ? ("padding-top" -: "60px !important")
```

Comment: Thanks! I needed to add parentheses (possibly due to to operator precedence) but it works that way!